# Validate hibernate date as long

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I want to validate a date in `Long` type to be greater than the current time.
I've seen `@Past`, `@Future` and so on... but It is not applicable to `Long` data type.

I'm looking for something like this:

```java
@FutureOrPresent
private Long dateStart;
@Future
private Long dateEnd;
```

But working for `Long` values.

How can I validate `date > System.currentTimeMillis()` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use existing constraint annotations but the types (Long in your case) on which you want to apply them are not supported you need to:

Create your own implementation of ConstraintValidator, for example:

```
public class FutureLongValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Future, Long> { 
    public boolean isValid(Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return true;
        }
        return value > System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Then register it so that HV knows about it and can use it for validation. There are a few ways how this can be done. I'd suggest using the ServiceLoader approach. To do that a file `META-INF/services/javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` must be created and the fully qualified name of the validator added to it:

```
some.package.FutureLongValidator
some.package.FutureOrPresentLongValidator
```

for a more detailed instructions and a sample project check out this post that covers the topic in details - [Adding custom constraint definitions via the Java service loader](https://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/)